# Is it safe to delete Windows Defender Scans History Files?

Tags: windows, log-files, windows-defender

OS: Windows 10 Pro (used as production server to host websites, and mail functions.)

I've noticed that de-fragmenting my hard drive (using MyDefrag v4.3.1) it's taking for ever to work itself through this `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Store` folder.

Looking further into it I found that this folder is over 26 GB in size and is holding over 2.3 million files. The file content is encrypted - so of no use to figure out what is stored. They date range is from 2016-04 to 2019-02 (the time I stopped using Defender.)

At the moment I am not using **Windows Defender** as antivirus software, but **G Data Antivirus** software. The reason I removed Windows Defender is because it was using 100% of the computers resources for an extended time, just making the system unusable. The server was again responsive after I switched. Checking into the remouval I looked at the [Windows features on or off tool - and it looks like Defender is not even listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMkgL.jpg).

Before running the defrag tool I did a Disk Cleanup System Files and removed all I could (Windows Defender logs are not listed in the list.) I also used the Remove Temporary Files tool offered in Windows 10 (but there too, no mention of Windows Defender log files.)

Your suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and deleted these files, after getting some help from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-it-safe-to-delete-windows-defender-antivirus/815317c0-9983-4516-855e-ad30ee05a7ee); and it worked.

From Post:

> There's no harm deleting the Windows Defender files on your computer. Deleting this file will not affect any of your applications or software on your computer since they're just temporary files. You can delete it to free up some space on your drive.

Answer (score -2):

if you don't know how to clear the Protection history just check out the video
https://youtu.be/vWyoptIYlak

Comment: Hello @Ejaz welcome on ServerFault. I suggest you to avoid link only answers because reliying on external resources could make the question unsueful in the future should the content be modified or removed. Take a look at [how to post a good answer here](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer).